# send email using flutter mailer package

Tags: flutter

How do I send email using flutter mailer package without enabling 'less secure app access' in google security. I want something similar like sending mail in NodeJS. Can anyone send a code snippet to understand better?

I have tried this

```
sendMail async() {
     String username = 'example@gmail.com';
     String password = 'password'; // Don't want to write my password in code

// Creating the Gmail server
     final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);

     final message = Message()
       ..from = Address(username)
       ..recipients.add('recipient@gmail.com')      //recipient email
       ..subject = 'Subject line'                   //subject of the email
      ..text = 'This is the plain text.\nThis is line 2 of the text part.';

     try {
       final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
       print('Message sent: ' +
           sendReport.toString());
     } on MailerException catch (e) {
       print('Message not sent. \n' +
           e.toString());
     }
```

If there is a way to just send mails **without mentioning password** , I would be glad to know it.

Comment: https://medium.com/@achinthaisuru444/sending-emails-using-flutter-f588387280db

Comment: Yes I have used the same reference, but I am looking for a way to no write password in the code itself. I want it to either send mail using just email or automatically authenticate just as we do in Node.js / Flask